# How to create API token via API in strapi v4

Tags: access-token, strapi

I didn't seem to find anything in the documentation but as long as it's done via the admin, it can be done via API.
How can I create  an API token via API?

Answer (score 3):

I dunno if that helps, but I was able to generate api tokens in the bootstrap function which is called when strapi starts up.

In `src/index.js` I added this;

```js
const lifespan_7_days_millis = 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
async function createE2EBearerTokenIfNotExist(strapi) {
    if (!process.env['IS_E2E']) {
        return;
    }
    const tokenService = strapi.service('admin::api-token');
    if (tokenService && tokenService.create) {
        const tokenAlreadyExists = await tokenService.exists({
            name: 'e2e-tests-token',
        });
        if (tokenAlreadyExists) {
            console.info(`an api token named 'e2e-tests-token' already exists, skipping...`);
        }
        else {
            console.info(`creating 'e2e-tests-token' api token`);
            const { accessKey } = await tokenService.create({
                name: 'e2e-tests-token',
                type: 'full-access',
                lifespan: lifespan_7_days_millis,
            });
            return accessKey;
        }
    }
}


exports.default = {

    register( /*{ strapi }*/) { },

    async bootstrap({ strapi }) {
        if (process.env['IS_E2E']) {
            const apiToken = await createE2EBearerTokenIfNotExist(strapi);
            // you can now use apiToken to call your REST endpoints
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a bit of "reverse engineering" the API by inspecting API calls in the browser but it turns out it's quite simple. To create a token via an API you have to call `/admin/api-tokens` endpoint.

Here's an example cURL request that does it:

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:1337/admin/api-tokens \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <jwt>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "lifespan": null,
    "description": "test description",
    "type": "full-access",
    "name": "test",
    "permissions": null
}'
```

`lifespan` is a number of miliseconds until the token expires (e.g. for 7 days it should be `604800000` (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000). If `null` - the token won't expire.

`description` is optional.

`type` can take following values:

- `full-access`
- `read-only`
- `custom`

In case of `custom` type, `permissions` should be a list of token permissions, e.g.:

```
{
    "name": "Custom permissions",
    "lifespan": null,
    "type": "custom",
    "permissions": [
        "api::article.article.find"
    ]
}
```

The issue is having an API token to call this API in the first place. I managed to make it work by creating an admin account first (`/admin/register-admin`) - which returns a token.